# How much prep is needed to paint automotive paint over random other paint

Tags: painting, repainting, paint-removal, preparation

I have this old metal lawn chair and I want to paint it with flake/candy/pearl/clear automotive spray paints.  Partly because I think it will be cool, and partly to practice before I screw up a motorcycle.

The front bottom corners of the legs were rusted and cracked and wouldn't hold weight, so I've welded those up and then ground it out smooth.  The bottom and back are showing some rust through the paint, and the holes where the bolts are holding the arms/legs on are wallowed out so I'll need to weld those closed and redrill as well.  And, of course, the paint around them now has quite a bit of PB Blaster on it.

I started to strip the paint, but it seems that it is adhered very well where there isn't other damage.  There's no flaking or anything in the main panels.  I've read and seen videos on repainting vehicles and know the general recommendation is that you don't need to go down to metal, just 600 grit or so down to solid paint so it will adhere.  And anywhere there is rust, I know I need to go down to metal to get rid of the surface rust and to verify there are no pits, holes, or cracks I need to weld up.  But what about the rest?  Do I need to strip off all of the paint, or is it fine to leave it on?  Is there any concern that the solvents in automotive paint (I haven't bought any yet, so I don't know if it will be water-based or not, etc) will react poorly with whatever random paint is already on the chair or anything like that?  Will normal degreaser solvents get the pb blaster off, or does it infect the paint such that those sections need to be stripped anyway?

[image: The Chair]
[image: Rusted back]
[image: Wallowed-out bolt hole]

Comment: This would probably be a better fit on the 
Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair site.

Comment: The best paint jobs start with the best prep.  Prep is about 90% of a paint job, which is why I do not like painting.  Too much work prepping.  Any defect(bumps, pits, dirt) in prep will show up in the paint.   Sand blasting that chair would not be too much prep.

Comment: @JACK, I thought of that, but I'm mainly concerned with the difference between using automotive paints over (what I assume are) non automotive paints (and pb blaster).  Everything I've read and watched on painting over automotive paints with new automotive paints seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: @DanLopez you are asking about automotive paint at as site that does not deal with automotive paint

Comment: I would just hit it with a pressure washer.  If the paint doesn't move, go ahead and paint over it.

Comment: Painting over rust is a lost cause. If you can't media blast to near white metal, you'll have problems.  I would start with media blast to SSPC-PC10 near white metal *on the rust* and honestly since it's in the blast cabinet *anyway*, just go ahead and take off that old paint.  Then solvent wipedown and immediate anti-rust primer.  For best look spray it, but **PLEASE** use PPE according to the paint's instructions. 2-part autopaint is loaded with isocyanates which can burn down your immune system **in one paint session**.  This is no time for that "youthful feeling of immortality".

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer your question. So would many others on here.
However we cannot because we do not know what paint is on that chair.
Without that information any answer is speculative.

Your only option is to spray on an inconspicuous area such as under the seat and wait for the result.

General info is enamel paints can be sprayed over most everything, ( The results will show what prep you had done or didn't)
Lacquers are more difficult. They don't play well with most other paints and will wrinkle, spot, peal, fisheye and do all sorts of things you do not want.

Bottom line is if you want to know what reaction you will get, you will have to spray and watch.